# Recreating DATAGRIDVIEW object for same form after once the form is closed, receiving Dispose exception error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

AS I mentioned I recently tried to work with creating objects at runtime programmatically which is working fine but as soon as I close the form having `DATAGRIDVIEW` and I try to reopen the form and when the `form_load` event is triggered and script run again to create `DATAGRIDVIEW`i receive the dispose exception error as shown `here is the code in my apps module where this problem is happening

```
    'EMPLOYEE_ADD_CMD_DB_UPDATE
    If SENDER = "EMPLOYEE_ADD_CMD" Then
        With EMPLOYEE_ADD_FRM
            SQL_CMD_TXT = "INSERT INTO `EMPLOYEES` VALUES(NULL,'" & .ADD_NAME_TXT.Text & "','" &
        .ADD_FATHER_NAME_TXT.Text & "','" & .ADD_DOB_TXT.Text & "','" & .ADD_DOJ_TXT.Text &
         "','" & .ADD_POSITION_TXT.Text & "','" & .ADD_EMP_STATUS_TXT.Text & "','" &
         .ADD_SALARY_TXT.Text & "','" & .ADD_EOF_TXT.Text & "','" & .ADD_REMARKS_TXT.Text & "');
         SELECT `EMPLOYEE_ID`,`NAME` FROM `employees`;"
        End With
    End If


    'EMPLOYEE CENTER LOAD DB_RETRIVAL
    If SENDER = "EMPLOYEE_CENTER_LOAD" Then
        SQL_CMD_TXT = " SELECT `EMPLOYEE_ID`,`NAME` FROM `employees`;"
        EMPLOYEE_CENTER_FRM.Controls.Add(OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW)
        With OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW
            .Size = New Size(171, 181)
            .Location = New Size(12, 141)
            .BackgroundColor = Color.PeachPuff
            .RowHeadersVisible = False

        End With
    End If`
```

Comment: Post your code together with your question and not in am image.

Comment: Someone is going to tell you anyway, but you should use **parameterized queries** and not string concatenation like you are doing. Not only is this highly **insecure**, it makes the code hard to read, and your code will choke on single quotes and some special characters. Looking forward to seeing the rest of the code eg form load & close and show how and where the variables like `SENDER` are defined. What you posted is not sufficient at all. What exactly is marked as disposed ? The datagrid, or something else ?

Comment: You're using the default instance of a Form, then dispose of it, then you try to reuse it but this time it's gone. Don't use default instances, create a new instance of a Form when you need one and `Close()` it when you're done with it. Or `Dispose()` when using `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: JIMI Thanks for the help, please elaborate it a bit for me I did not understand can you show me how to create a new instance of a form that will really help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't close or dispose the object until its required. 
once its all done then close or dispose it, otherwise create a new object to work with as the closed or disposed object cant be call again its once closed its gone anyway cant recall